# Get grid.colum of a rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles

I have a xaml defined like so :

```
<Grid>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="3" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="4" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="5" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="6" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="7" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="8" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="9" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="10" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
   <Rectangle Grid.Column="11" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
</Grid>
```

What I don't find is a way to access the grid column number I,ve tried to cast the rectangle but I don't find the apropriate property of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `Rectangle` object you can get it using **[GetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** method. Say `rect` is object name then you can get it like this:

```
int column = (int)rect.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
```

`Grid.Column` is attached property and not normal Dependency Property of Rectangle. Hence you have to pass `Grid.ColumnProperty` in there.

Comment: I see thank you, didn't know I can get a property value throught GetValue

Comment: Glad to help Mokmeuh..!!

Answer (score 0):

`Grid.Column` is an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) and hence defines the static getter and setter methods [Grid.GetColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.getcolumn.aspx) and [Grid.SetColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumn.aspx). Please pay special attention to the [Attached Properties in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx#attached_properties_code) section of the linked MSDN article.

The usual way to get the value of the `Grid.Column` property in code is to call the static getter method:

```
int column = Grid.GetColumn(rect);
```